# system call variable splitting because of space in value in php

Tags: php

I am calling two system variables in a file and when fetching the variables in the page, the value is splitting into two.

**Here is my code**

```
system('php '.$app_name.'/send_survey_mail.php '.$name ." ". $name_person."  ".$location.' > mail_text.txt', $output);
```

If am passing values like name "John emmanual" and location "United States", it's splitting into two because of space. Can any one please help solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you do this anyways? Why don't you use the code from send_survey_mail.php directly?

Answer (score 0):

hey use the double quotes in command:

```
system('php '.$app_name.'/send_survey_mail.php "'.$name.'" "'. $name_person.'"  "'.$location.'" > mail_text.txt', $output);
```